# How to recover corrupted photo files?

Tags: data-corruption

All picture files are corrupted stored in Nash drive. Getting the below message when try to open in photo viewer. How to recover the photos? There are lots of photos old and recent.

> Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because either Photo Viewer doesn't support this file format, or you don't have the latest updates to Photo Viewer.

Comment: NAS drive? Is the drive itself reporting errors? How is the NAS mounted? What operating system and program are you viewing with?

Comment: Nash = Flash? Also, what type of image files?

Comment: @mattdm – Windows? b/c "Windows Photo Viewer"

Comment: If the files are truly corrupt, you can't recover them. Consider this a lesson to keep backups. (Which reminds me...)

Comment: Maybe? I suppose it's no use guessing.

Comment: Are  you sure the files are actually corrupt? Is it possible they are in in image format that your current version of Windows Photo Viewer does not support?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the NAS with your file explorer:

- Is the directory structure intact (ie, can you see the directories you have set up?)
- Are the size of the files (and possibly their time stamps) coherent with what you know of them
- Can you open the file with any kind of image viewer (try several image applications, you can always open the files in Firefox/Chrome)
- If you use the explorer to copy a files form the NAS to the local disk, does the copy occur without any warning/error message? Is the resulting file the right size? Can you open it in an image viewer?

If the answer is no to any of this, the best course of action is to stop the NAS, and bring it to someone with some computer experience.

Comment: The error message indicates the problem is related to file format, not drive accessibility.

Comment: The message just implies that Photoviewer didn't see the bytes it expected. Assuming the pictures aren't in some exotic format, it is likely that their content has changed or is not read correctly (disk or NAS or network error). If I had this happen to me, I would open the file with a binary editor and check the headers(and likely see a long string of NUL bytes). But then I wouldn't be asking here, so I assume that this is outside the OP's current computer skills.